# Left to right references in rtl latex template

Tags: latex, xelatex

I have a rtl latex template. I use below code for bibliography:

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{MyReferences}
```

The references now shown rtl. but I want they be ltr. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to add `\selectlanguage{english}` before `\bibliography{MyReferences}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Romain Picot mentioned in comments I add `\selectlanguage{english}` before `\bibliography{MyReferences}`

Comment: This looks a better solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649164/26535